# How to add a custom label next to an external component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular and Kendo Grid, and I want to display a custom label next to the Kendo Grid Column Chooser. The default  component only shows an icon, and I cannot find a way to add a label next to it.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <kendo-grid [data]="data">
         <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
            // I want to add lable like "Choose Columns"
            <kendo-grid-column-chooser></kendo-grid-column-chooser>
         </ng-template>
         <kendo-grid-column field="Field1"></kendo-grid-column>
         <kendo-grid-column field="Field2" [hidden]="true"></kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
    `
})

class AppComponent {
    public data: any[] = [{ Field1: 'Foo', Field2: 'Bar' }];
}
```

I want to display a custom label (e.g., "Choose Columns") next to the Column Chooser button (external component), so the users can understand its purpose more efficiently. I can add label, but when clicking the label I am unable to trigger the action. How can I achieve this in an Angular application?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try by adding a custom `::before { content: 'choose column'; }` css rule for this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `kendo-grid-column-chooser` component in `label` like so:

```
<label style="display:flex;align-items:center;cursor:pointer">
   <span>Choose Columns</span>
   <kendo-grid-column-chooser></kendo-grid-column-chooser>
</label>
```

I tried it out on StackBlitz starting from here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/ and it works.